# How to add method to a multiple variables

Tags: javascript

I'm refactoring my code and wanted to lessen the lines of code I've made, here's my code:

```
let { user, change_log, new_value, old_value } = req.query;

user = user.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
change_log = change_log.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
new_value = new_value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
old_value = old_value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
```

So I wanted to make it like single or couple of line of code like this:

```
user, change_log, new_value, old_value =
        (user, change_log, new_value, old_value).replace(/'/g, "\\'");
```

So that I don't have to repeat every variable just to add a replace method. Is this possible or should I stick with the current solution?

Thanks for those who will answer and please correct me if I'm doing a bad practice in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an array from the values and use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on it. Use [Destructuring Assignment without declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration):

```
let { user, change_log, new_value, old_value } = req.query;
[user, change_log, new_value, old_value] = 
     [user, change_log, new_value, old_value].map(a => a.replace(/'/g, "\\'"))
```

**Note:** The previous line must have `;` at the end. Otherwise, it will consider the `[]` as bracket notation for `req.query`. Something like this:

```
req.query[user, change_log, new_value, old_value]
```

Comment: you have extra dot in the map function `a..replace`

Comment: I didn't know that you could map variables, I only used it to manipulate objects thanks for your help.

Comment: @Lee we are not mapping variables. We are creating an array from the vairables and then using map and destrcuturing

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't notice the square brackets thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**Destructuring** is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays into distinct variables. That is, we can extract data from arrays and objects and assign them to variables.

```
[user, change_log, new_value, old_value] =
        [user, change_log, new_value, old_value].map(res=> res.replace(/'/g, "\\'"));
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use an array of key names, `.replace` each of them, and create an object instead of 4 standalone variables:

```
const vals = ['user', 'change_log', 'new_value', 'old_value']
  .reduce((a, prop) => {
    a[prop] = req.query[prop].replace(/'/g, "\\'");
    return a;
  }, {});

// then, eg, reference vals.user
```

If you *need* multiple standalone variables, then your code will have to be a bit WET - list them all when destructuring, and list them all when iterating over properties:

```
const [user, change_log, new_value, old_value] = ['user', 'change_log', 'new_value', 'old_value']
  .map(prop => req.query[prop].replace(/'/g, "\\'"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorter this by using an array

```
let { user, change_log, new_value, old_value } = req.query;
[user, change_log, new_value, old_value] =
  [user, change_log, new_value, old_value].map(str => str.replace(/'/g, "\\'"));
```

or somehow. But better create a function that will do replace, and use it.